# HTTP 400 Bad Request while sending more number of characters with the URL to server

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, servlets, http-headers

I am developing one React application, using the fetch API, I am sending one request along with some query parameters in the URL to server.
Getting **400 bad request** when the length of the characters in the URL exceeds 7700 characters in the chrome browser.

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ parametername: parametervalue})
};
fetch(URL, requestOptions)
```

[image]
Please help me with how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

According to this, you can't have url that is 7000+ characters long. Consider finding a different way to implement?

Comment: Thanks for the response.Actually I need to pass this json object to server. Is there any way to compress the json object to shorten the length.As fetch api is the only one which I know to post data to server from react.